# Defining which record to be used in decision splits with 1-M relationship

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I am building a Journey based on Cases within Salesforce (via Salesforce Data entry).

Before each touch point I want to check to see if the case is still Open before the next step, I want to know how I can do this as the Contact Data attributes will just look for any record where Case.Status = Open instead of the one thats been injected into the Journey.

I wanted to know whether defining an additional attribute like `Case ID = Journey Data.Case.ID AND Contact Data.Case.Status = Open` would work? and if not how have other people got round this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One-to-many relationships work fine in Journey Builder, and should be used exactly how you describe it.

When you need to check for a specific relationship, e.g. only that specific case, then you can use attribute to attribute comparison to ensure you are looking at the exact record you need - taking the case id from Journey Data, as this defines the case we are interested in verifying in the given split.